# jena expression function to return a RDFList

Tags: sparql, jena

I wonder if there it is possible to write an expression function  (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/writing_functions.html) that returns an RDFList.

## Context:

The all idea is to be able to transform the result of a group concat into an rdfList. This would be in the context of writing a query and a subquery, where the outter query would match the element of the returned RDFList.

## Note:

Given that the expression Function return valueNode, i checked if there is anything that could help. I spotted

`public class NodeValueNode extends NodeValue`

Anyhow, i am not sure as to how the all thing might work (if it does). Some pointers, indication on how to go about this, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding now is that this is not possible at all. Returning a Graph is only possible with a Construct query. A Construct can not be a subquery. So in essence this should not just work

However to do this kind of things, one can just use magic properties as listed here jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-propfunc.html e.g. apf:strSplit. So doing a group_concat in the subQuery and using apf:strSplit to subsequently pattern match over the list

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX apf: <http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/property#>

SELECT ?col

WHERE {


{
    SELECT ?group (group_concat(?elt) as ?list)
    WHERE {
            VALUES (?group ?elt)  
            {
                ("col1"  "Hello1")
                ("col1"  "World1")
                ("col2"  "Hello2")
                ("col2"  "World2")
            } 
    } GroupBy ?group
}
    
?listElt apf:strSplit (?list  " ").

BIND(CONCAT(?group, "_", ?listElt) AS ?col )
}
```

We get

Col

```
col1_Hello1
col1_World1
col2_Hello2
col2_World2
```